# Java: Multi Dimensional array output confusion?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
public class VarNoOfCols {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int[3][];

        a[0]=new int[3];
        a[1]=new int[2];
        a[2]=new int[1];
        int temp=3;
        for(int i =0; i<3;i++) {
            for(int k=0;k<temp;k++) {
                a[i][k]= k*10;
                           temp-- ;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

--- output that I assumed ---- is below ---But this is incorrect.

```
(0 0) 0  (0 1) 10
(1 0) 0  (1 1) 10
(2 0) 0  (2,1) 10
```

I know this is incorrect. (My question is - on completing second iteration, "k" is greater than "temp" and when conditon fails it will stop the inner statments and do the next job (what ever it suppose to be).Why am i getting (0,2) = 20 and why i dont see (2,1) = 10 ?

You can see the correct output:

```
(0 0) 0  (0 1) 10 (0 2) 20
(1 0) 0  (1 1) 10
(2 0) 0
```

I am a learner and i really appreciate someone's help here. thank you

Comment: The programm you gave return the 2nd output (the one you said is correct) so I don't understand your question, and what is the first output you told about? Do you want to know why your app is giving you the 2nd output?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where

Comment: To alain - Yes, I am getting 2nd output. I have no clue why I am getting the 2nd output as specified. I am expecting the first output that I have mentioned. can anyone explain please?

Comment: @MKod You can't obtain the first output see my answer to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code like that:

```
for(int i =0; i<3;i++)
{
    for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
        a[i][k]= k*10;

}
```

If you wanted a square output, why do you use the control variable `temp` that will change the number of outputted entries on each iteration over `i`?

Answer (score 0):

this is because the temp and the k

in your program first i=0

1. k=0,temp=3 then (0 0) so output 0*10 = 0
2. k=1,temp=2 then (0 1) so output 1*10 = 10
3. k=2,temp=1 condition false in for loop (there  the condition in the outer for loop(having i) is correct but in the inner for loop the condation k

i=1

1. k=0,temp=3 then (1 0) so output 0*10 = 0
2. k=1,temp=2 then (1 1) so output 1*10 = 10

i=2

1. k=0,temp=3 then (2 0) so output 0*10 = 0
2. k=1,temp=2 then (2 1) so output 1*10 = 10

there is no need of `temp`. to get correct output use this

```
for(int i =0; i<3;i++)
{
   for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
      a[i][k]= k*10;

}
```

Comment: The temp variable should be inside the (inner) 2nd loop. I am sorry initially I have given temp variable outside inner loop (2nd) .I am getting the 2nd output and not the first one as you and me (Mayank) expected. Can you please explain? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Actually with your last edit (with temp-- in the second for) you obtain neither the first nor the second output.

***Why?***

Because you never reassign `temp` and after 3 time be decremented the second loop will not be executed anymore. So you got a value for (0;0) (0;1) and (1;0) only.

***Why you can't obtain output 1 (square one)?***

```
a[2] have a size of 1 so you can't have something in (2;1)
```

***How to obtain the second output?***

Don't put the `temp--` in the second loop but after the second loop (at the end of the first loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VarNoOfCols {           
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        int a[][] = new int[3][];

        a[0]=new int[3];
        a[1]=new int[2];
        a[2]=new int[1];

        int temp=3;

        for(int i =0; i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<temp;k++)
                //the inner for lopp doesn't have curly "{" braces.
                //temp will be 3 for 1st loop and when k becomes 3 it exit inner loop.
                a[i][k]= k*10;
            temp--;
        }
        //temp--;
        //System.out.println("temp : " +temp + " \n " );

    }   
}
```

Thank you guys. I figuered out the logic behind. it is not logic, it is just that `{` that should be watched. I will get following output if I don't use braces `{` in inner loop:

```
(0 0 ) 0   (0 1 ) 10   (0 2 ) 20
(1 0 ) 0   (1 1 ) 10
(2 0 ) 0
```

If the braces `{` and `}` present in inner loop with temp variable inside inner loop then I will get the following output:

```
(0 0 ) 0   (0 1 ) 10
(1 0 ) 0
```

Comment: It's logic...If you don't put `{}` after the for loop only the first following statement is considered to be in the for-loop.